# Forcibly making a node a source in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) and I want to perform the operation of forcibly making a given node a source node, by reversing all its incoming edges, and the incoming edges of its parents, grandparents, etc. It seems that equivalently one can simply reverse the subgraph induced by its ancestors + the node itself

1. Does this operation have a name?
2. Is the result a DAG again?
3. What if I want to make a whole set of nodes sources? Do I need to apply the operation sequentially in reverse topological order?

#### Example:

The target node is (3). Going in topological order, we first reverse the incoming arrows of (1), then the incoming arrows of (2) and finally the incoming arrows of (3).

```
(1)→(2) | (1)→(2) | (1)←(2) | (1)←(2) 
   ↘︎ ↓  |    ↘︎ ↓  |   ↘︎  ↓  |    ↖ ↑  
    (3) |     (3) |     (3) |     (3)
```

The result is the same as simply reversing the arrows of the original graph.

---

#### Pseudocode:

````
invert_on_node(Graph G, node n):
   A = anscestors(G, n)
   H = G.subgraph(A+n)

   G.delete_edges(H.edges)

   for node in topological_sort(H):
       reverse_incoming_edges(H, node)

   G.add_edges(H.edges)
```
````

Comment: What if two of the node's parents have an arc between them?  Either way you orient it, it seems to violate your condition?

Comment: If you want to make a node a source, it's enough to reverse all its incoming edges; dealing with its former ancestors is unnecessary.

Comment: @MishaLavrov that is not what I want to do. I added pseudo-code that described the procedure I am interested in

Comment: @MatthewDaly I added this as an example, I hope it is clearer now what I want to do.

Comment: I think that you want to reverse the edges of every path that ends in your chosen node. So take the set of edges that is the union of all those paths, and reverse its elements. This is equivalent to taking the subgraph consiting of the chosen node and its ancestors, and reversing all its edges. If you insist on implementing it in a particular vertex order, take care that the order does not flip any edge multiple times, or else the result will be dependent on the order For multiple sources simultaneously, just use the subgraph of those nodes and their ancestors to make order not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 2, it turns out the proof is trivial:

**Claim:** Let $G=(V, E)$ be a DAG. Then, for all $v\in V$, the graph $G' = (V, E_v^R \dot\cup (E\setminus E_v))$ obtained by reversing all edges contained in the subgraph $G[A(v)] = (V_v, E_v)$ induced by the set of ancestors $A(v) = \{u\in G\mid u\le v\}$ is also a DAG.

**Proof:** Let $B=V\setminus A(v)$ and $p$ be an arbitrary path in $G'$. We observe that once $p$ enters $B$, it can never go back into $A(v)$, since all edges with only one node in $A(v)$ must point outwards into $B$, otherwise $A(v)$  would not include all ancestors. But that means we can split the path into 3 parts: one part contained in $A(v)$, a single edge from $A(v)$ into $B$ and a part contained in $B$. Since both $A(v)^R$ and $B$ are DAGs, this implies $p$ must be circle free.